# Jenkins Extended E-mail won't print $GIT_BRANCH or $GIT_COMMIT

Tags: git, jenkins

In the Jenkins "Extended E-mail Notification" plugin, I have created a table about the Build and Git reversion numbers, getting the values through the environment variables that Jenkins sets. All of the table entries are fine apart from the $GIT_COMMIT & $GIT_BRANCH parts.  It outputs the strings "$GIT_COMMIT" & "$GIT_BRANCH" respectively.  I tried using {} around the environment variable name, with no effect on the output.

```
<table border="0">
<tr><td><b>Project:</b>  </td><td> <b>$PROJECT_NAME</b></td></tr>
<tr><td>Build #:         </td><td> $BUILD_NUMBER</td></tr>
<tr><td>Status:          </td><td> $BUILD_STATUS</td></tr>
<tr><td>Git reversion #: </td><td> $GIT_COMMIT</td></tr>
<tr><td>Git branch:      </td><td> $GIT_BRANCH</td></tr>
<tr><td>Changes:         </td><td> $CHANGES</td></tr>
</table>
```

I check that these environment varables exist at the build command line output.  Why do they not appear in the email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build variables, like `$PROJECT_NAME` and `$BUILD_NUMBER` are available directly, since they are created in this build session.

For environment variables, you have to use the following syntax:
`${ENV, var="GIT_COMMIT"}`