# Jenkins Git Plugin Repository Url Variable

Tags: git, jenkins

Is it possible to use a variable in the repository url for the jenkins git plugin?

```
https://${GIT_USER}@github.com/e82eric/Prompts.git
```

When I try it looks like `${GIT_USER}` is passed instead of the substitution.

Comment: There seem to be some places in Jenkins where `$GIT_USER` should be used instead of `${GIT_USER}`. Have you tried to access the variable w/o the brackets?

Comment: Both seem to seem to produce the same result: Cloning repository https://%24GIT_USER@github.com/e82eric/Prompts.git  Cloning repository https://%24{GIT_USER}@github.com/e82eric/Prompts.git

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650860) suggests that `${ENV, var="GIT_USER"}` may work for environment variables, while the standard syntax should work for 'build variables'.

Comment: Still the same problem:   Cloning repository https://%24{ENV%2c%20var%3d"GIT_USER"}@github.com/e82eric/Prompts.git

Comment: If you manually edit the job's `config.xml` does the repo url appear with the html-safe character codes? If so, does it work if you replace them from the config file? If not, I'd guess that they are purposefully not supporting variables in repo URLs due to the potential polling complications.

Comment: It shows up in the xml the same as the UI.  <url>https://${GIT_USER}@github.com/e82eric/Prompts.git</url>

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I'm facing the exact same thing right now

Comment: It looks like this issue has been filed many times over the course of the past few years and they never "accepted" a fix. There have been fixes but the admins closed the issue as "Won't fix".
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa

Comment: @e82.eric: did you manage to get this working as of 2020-06-24?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Jenkins Git-Plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), this should be working by now (Feb-2015).

Among the issues that were resolved:

- [**JENKINS-14276**](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14276) - *Git SCM-polling doesn't work when using a parametrized branch-name*
- [**JENKINS-20427**](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20427) - *Build Parameter variable in branch name causes polling to detect false changes in GIT*
- [**JENKINS-23675**](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23675) - *The git plugin is not working correctly when the repository url has job parameter and any repository credentials*
- [**JENKINS-24786**](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24786) - *Since 2.2.6, environment variables are not expanded in git publisher*

Comment: Gonen - are you sure? I'm on Jenkins v. 2.222.1 and if I set Git URL to ${MY_GIT}/myrepo.git - then ${MY_GIT} is not evaluated on fetch. How do you achieve this?

Comment: @user1876484, I am surely not sure :)  This was five years ago - things may have broke 17 times since I wrote this answer

Answer (score 2):

BEST SOLUTION - 100% works

First place the entire Repository url with no variables under Environment variables.
Example:
Let's say i want to put https://f4567123902345@github.google.com/ero/myProject under Repostiory Url in Pipeline from scm
Dashboard -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure the System -> Environment variables
Click on Add

[image] [[image]

Now go to the Repository Url and place ${RepoUrl} there
[image]

Finally (Important step)
Uncheck the Lightweight checkout at the bottom
[image]

Build It -> Success

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> It looks like this issue has been filed many times over the course of the past few years and they never "accepted" a fix. There have been fixes but the admins closed the issue as "Won't fix".

**References**

- [Build Parameter variable in branch name causes polling to detect false changes in GIT](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20427)